# How to send DHCPD leases to remote syslog-ng

Tags: dhcp, syslog, snmp

I want to query a DHCP server for logs about leased IP’s every 5 minutes. I am not sure how to run the query from my server or which file to edit.

The queried logs will be sent to the server and placed into a MySQL database which I have created.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` (or `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhcpd.leases`) file. The [somewhat outdated manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/dhcpd.leases.5.html) says you might have to create the file with `touch` first. I don't remember ever having to do that.

As to the MySQL part, if you don't have that figured out already, you might use some dynamic scripting language like Python or Perl with either standard access module, or some ORM (like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)) for richer but more complicated setup. Any questions about that would be more suited for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) though

Comment: I want the logs to be sent to a remote syslog server. then i will use cron tab to have the query repeated every 5 minutes

Comment: @sosytee I guess then that those details should be included in the original question, as sending stuff to a local `syslog` or filtering it and sending to a remote daemon is quite another matter. The question should read 'How to send DPCPD leases to remote syslogd' or something in that line. Please edit accordingly.